# Converting varchar column to Date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using MSSQL server .
I have a column named logDate which is of varchar type.

I have to perform operation like ' I have to delete the records which are older than 10 days '.

Which query i can use to perform this operation ?

How to convert the varchar to Date type ?

Here logDate varchar is in the format ddmmyyyy

I searched i got few links but i am not able to perform this operation.

Thanks for your time :)

[image]

Comment: The *real* question is why are you storing dates as a `varchar` in the first place? There are 6 date and time data types, and all of them are infinitely more appropriate for the data you want to store. Fix your design, fix the problem.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for your feedback , it table is bit old , we are now supposed to include this feature , thats the reason we cannot change the table design

Comment: Date and time data types have existed for decades... "It's old" isn't an excuse, nor does it change the fact that the solution is to fix the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `delete`.  The trick is converting `logdate` to a real date:

```
delete t
    where datefromparts(right(logdate, 4), substring(logdate, 3, 2), left(logdate, 2)) < dateadd(day, -10, convert(date, getdate()));
```

This deconstructs the MMDDYYYY format into the year, the month, and the date and then constructs a date from those components.

Note:  This assumes that you don't actually care about the specific time.

Another way to convert the times uses string conversions:

```
where convert(date, right(logdate, 4) + left(logdate, 4)) < dateadd(day, -10, convert(date, getdate())
```

This restructures the string as YYYYMMDD, which is a standard format that is readily converted from a string to a date.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to simply convert this to date:

```
declare @date nvarchar(max) = '12032020'

select cast(substring(@date, 5, 4)+substring(@date, 3, 2)+substring(@date, 1, 2) AS date)
```